# order mysql result don't have same result it 2 computers

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I program something in my own laptop(apache,Ubuntu Os) (with php,CodeIgniter) and it will order result by DESC,but when I ran it on other computer (easyphp,win32) it didn't do it.

so I have not same result ,where is the problem and how should I solve it?

I don't wanna use `order id by desc`

Comment: `order id by desc` isn't valid syntax.

Comment: Why dont you want to use order by ? thats the only certain way to order data across multiple databases

Comment: Your question sounds like you do not want to use `ORDER BY` at all. In this case you cannot ensure a particular order. If you only order by non-unique fields you also cannot ensure the order of rows where all fields listed in the ORDER statement are unique.

Comment: why the same code have different problem in two computers.

Comment: @Moein7tl: "why does the inside of my neighbor's house look different than the inside of my house? They're both houses!" Compare the MySQL settings on the two machines, compare the table setup, etc...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a consistent record order with a MySQL query, you **must** use the `ORDER BY` clause.  If you refuse to use it, then you must write a sorting function in your script (to use with the `usort()` PHP function) to sort the data consistently.